# Error Message about Array Arguments in Code for Mean

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a variable length (L) that changes for each particle in a group of a few hundred thousand particles with every time step. I'm trying to add a code that will tell me the average length of the particles at each time step in the model. I keep getting this error: "An array-valued argument is required in this context" for my mean equation. What does this mean? It seems to have a problem with my length variable, which I extract from the model using get_state. Here is my code:

```
function checkstatus(ng,g,time) result(validsim)
    use utilities
    implicit none
    logical :: validsim
    integer, intent(in)      :: ng
    type(igroup), intent(in) :: g(ng)
    real(sp), intent(in)     :: time
    real(sp), pointer        :: L(:)
    real(sp), dimension(ng)  :: mean
    integer, pointer         :: istatus(:)
    integer, allocatable     :: mark(L)
    integer :: n,NI
    integer, save :: dumphead = 0

    do n=1,ng
    NI = g(n)%Nind
    call get_state('L',g(n),L)
    mean(NI) = sum(L(NI)) / size(L(NI))
    end do

    write(*,103)time,mean(NI)
```

Comment: `L(NI)` is not an array, it is one element, one number. You cannot ask for the size of that number. There is likely some duplicate.

Comment: We have enough information to tell you what's going wrong, but not enough information to help you find what you should be doing instead. What are you trying to do? What are each of your variables? What does `get_state` do?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `L` is a pointer to a one-dimensional `real` array, and so `L(NI)` is a scalar `real`. The intrinsics `sum` and `size` take array arguments, so the statement `sum(L(NI)) / size(L(NI))` is invalid.

Comment: Thank you. Is it impossible to take the mean of my lengths when they are in this form or do I just need to write a different code for it?

Comment: The problem is it is far from clear to me what you want to do. `Sum( L ) / Size( L )` will give the mean of the values held in the L array, is this what you want?